# Changing the values of infoBox from selectInput

Tags: r, shiny, infobox

I have a dashboard with select Input for species and info Boxes to display total species by state. Running the code below will display for one of the boxes. How can the other values be displayed? The output for the boxes should be as shown below e.g for info box Arizona AZ elk 5 etc. There are 3 info boxes for the states and select input has three options. The screen shot of the output is also attached[image]

```
suppressPackageStartupMessages(library(tidyverse))
library(sf)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ungulates = c("elk", "mule deer", "pronghorn")
regions = c("AZ", "NV", "WY")

ung_shape1 <- tibble("species" = rep(ungulates[1], 5), "state" = rep(regions[1], 5))

ung_shape2 <- tibble("species" = rep(ungulates[1], 3), "state" = rep(regions[2], 3))

ung_shape3 <- tibble("species" = rep(ungulates[1], 4), "state" = rep(regions[3], 4))

ung_shape4 <- tibble("species" = rep(ungulates[2], 6), "state" = rep(regions[1], 6))

ung_shape5 <- tibble("species" = rep(ungulates[2], 7), "state" = rep(regions[2], 7))

ung_shape6 <- tibble("species" = rep(ungulates[2], 4), "state" = rep(regions[3], 4))

ung_shape7 <- tibble("species" = rep(ungulates[3], 4), "state" = rep(regions[1], 4))

ung_shape8 <- tibble("species" = rep(ungulates[3], 2), "state" = rep(regions[2], 2))

all_ung <- bind_rows(ung_shape1, ung_shape2, ung_shape3, ung_shape4, ung_shape5, ung_shape6, ung_shape7, ung_shape8)

geomt <- tibble(x = runif(n=35), y = runif(n = 35))
ung_sff <- bind_cols(all_ung, geomt)
ung_sf <- ung_sff %>% st_as_sf(coords = c("x", "y"))



ui <- dashboardPage(skin = "red", 
                    dashboardHeader(title = "Ungulates"), 
                    dashboardSidebar(disable = TRUE),
                    dashboardBody(
                      fluidRow(
                        box(width = 10, title = "Select input", #background = "fuchsia",
                            status = "primary", solidHeader = TRUE,
                            br(),
                            
                            selectInput("ungul", "Choose a species",
                                        choices = unique(ung_sf$species)))
                        
                        
                      ),
                      br(),
                      br(),
                      br(),
                      
                      
                      fluidRow(
                        
                        infoBoxOutput("azCount"),
                        infoBoxOutput("nvCount"),
                        infoBoxOutput("wyCount")
                      )
                      
                    )
)








server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  
  output$azCount <- renderInfoBox({
    
    species_state <- ung_sf %>% select(species, state)
    species_state <- st_drop_geometry(species_state)
    infoaz <- filter(species_state, species %in% input$ungul)
    countaz <- infoaz %>% group_by(state) %>% count(species)
    
    infoBox(
      "Arizona", icon = icon("tree"), color = "maroon", head(countaz, 1)
      
    )
    
    
    
  })
  
  output$nvCount <- renderInfoBox({
    
    
    
    infoBox(
      "Nevada", icon = icon("tree"), color = "navy"
    )
  })
  
  output$wyCount <- renderInfoBox({
    
    
    
    infoBox(
      "Wyoming", icon = icon("tree"), color = "olive"
    )
  })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: This is not reproducible. What kind of object does `"ung.RDATA"` contain? Is the sample data you give a representation of `"ung_combined"`? Please share data in a reproducible & unambiguous format (e.g. using `dput`). Then make sure that any code you share can be reproduced based on the information & details you include.

Comment: *"You can use the data given above as a simple example"* No we can't. Data included is incomplete. Please use `dput` to share minimal & reproducible data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The server function should be

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  
  
  output$azCount <- renderInfoBox({
    
    species_state <- ung_combined %>% select(species, state)
    species_state <- st_drop_geometry(species_state)
    infoaz <- filter(species_state, species %in% input$ungul)
    countaz <- subset(infoaz, state == "AZ") %>% count(species)
    
    infoBox(
      "Arizona", icon = icon("tree"), color = "maroon", head(countaz, 1)
     
    )
    
    
    
  })
  
  output$nvCount <- renderInfoBox({
             species_state <- ung_sf %>% select(species, state)
             species_state <- st_drop_geometry(species_state)
             infonv <- filter(species_state, species %in% input$ungul)
              countnv <- subset(infonv, state == "NV") %>% count(species)
    
    infoBox(
      "Nevada", icon = icon("tree"), color = "navy", head(countnv, 1)
    )
  })
  
  output$wyCount <- renderInfoBox({
         species_state <- ung_sf %>% select(species, state)
         species_state <- st_drop_geometry(species_state)
         infowy <- filter(species_state, species %in% input$ungul)
         countwy <- subset(infowy, state == "WY") %>% count(species)


    infoBox(
      "Wyoming", icon = icon("tree"), color = "olive", head(countwy, 1)
    )
  })
}



shinyApp(ui, server)
```